# js file triggers automatically while testing ;

Tags: javascript, node.js

here when testcases.js is executed, even without any testcases, three consoles appear via function "trigger" ; Is this normal behavior? How to test just single function say (function one) without triggering the whole code.

```
    a.js:

    trigger()

function trigger() {
    one();
    two();
    three();
}

function one(){
    console.log("one")
    return "one"
}

function two(){
    console.log("two")
    return "two"
}

function three(){
    console.log("three")
    return "three"
}

module.exports = {
    one : one,
    two : two,
    three : three
}

testcases.js

var alpha = require("a.js")

    describe("Testing 1234Random in string scenario ", function() {     
    it("should return true ",function(){
        assert.equal(alpha.one(),"one") // position of the first string
    });
});
```

Comment: because you have "trigger()" at the beginning, this causes the trigger function to be invoked. remove this and problem will be solve.

Comment: Instead of calling trigger() at the first line call the one()

Comment: But my actual code needs trigger to be invoked before anything else.

Comment: then add conditions in the trigger function, like if condition a is true then call a and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the trouble. Simple tweak helped me out .

I need removed functions one, two, three and placed in another file (Say b.js) While testing I used b.js; For the sake of the normal flow of code, I imported b.js in a.js;
Thus My code works without its flow disturbing my testing.